# setState causes infinite loop even though it is outside render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently developing a simple weather app using openweatherapp API. The app is developed to fetch data from two endpoints: one that returns the current weather in your city and the other one that returns the weather forecast for next 5 days. The app should also fire an event after 60 seconds that re-fetches the data. This is how I tried to architecture my solution:

In App.js I am fetching the data and then I am passing it down as props to two other components, one that handles the current weather and the other one, the weather forecast. In the CurrentWeatherForecast component I am also initiating the function that updates the state every second using hooks. When the timer reaches 60 seconds I am calling the "handleRefresh" function that I have passed down as a prop from App.js. (in App.js is where the actual update happens). The "handleRefresh" function is outside the render method of App.js and it updates a "step" variable that should then cause the component to re-render and to re-fetch the data. The issue is that upon calling setState the function causes an infinite loop which I don't understand why since the function is outside the render method. I will post my code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { CurrentWeatherForecast } from "./components/CurrentWeatherForecast";
import { NextDaysWeatherForecast } from "./components/NextDaysWeatherForecast";

export class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentWeather: [],
        nextDaysWeather: [],
        step: 0,
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    var currentWeather;
    var nextDaysWeather; // step is used to indicate wether I want to fetch data or not
    if (step === 0) {
        fetch(
            "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=1fc71092a81b329e8ce0e1ae88ef0fb7"
        )
            .then((response) => {
                const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
                if (
                    !contentType ||
                    !contentType.includes("application/json")
                ) {
                    throw new TypeError("No JSON data!");
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                currentWeather = data;
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        fetch(
            "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&appid=1fc71092a81b329e8ce0e1ae88ef0fb7"
        )
            .then((response) => {
                const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
                if (
                    !contentType ||
                    !contentType.includes("application/json")
                ) {
                    throw new TypeError("No JSON data!");
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                let requiredData = data.list.slice(0, 5);
                nextDaysWeather = requiredData;
            })
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
        let f = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                currentWeather: currentWeather,
                nextDaysWeather: nextDaysWeather,
                step: 1, // updating step to 1 after fetching the data
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
}

handleRefresh = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    console.log(step);
    this.setState({ step: 0 }); // updating the step to 0 this causes the infinite loop
};

render() {
    const { currentWeather, nextDaysWeather } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <CurrentWeatherForecast
                currentWeather={currentWeather}
                handleRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
            />
            <NextDaysWeatherForecast nextDaysWeather={nextDaysWeather} />
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

This was in App.js Ignore the NextDaysWeatherForecast component as it is empty for now

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const CurrentWeatherForecast = (props) => {
const { currentWeather } = props;
const [progressValue, setValue] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setValue((progressValue) =>
            progressValue < 61 ? progressValue + 1 : (progressValue = 0)
        );
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
if (progressValue === 60) {
    props.handleRefresh(); // calling the handleRefresh function passed from App.js
}

return (
    <div>
        <label htmlFor="file">Downloading progress:</label>
        <progress id="file" value={progressValue} max="60">
            {progressValue}%
        </progress>
    </div>
);
};
```

And this was the NextWeatherForecast component where I am initiating the timer and then calling the "handleRefresh" function that I have passed down as a prop.

Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: First, change `this.setState({ step: 0 });` to `this.setState(prev => {( ...prev, step: 0 }))` and see what happens, unless you did it intentionally. In your code currentWeather and nextDaysWeather are undefined right after you set step to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this effect-phase and render-phase code, and try to guess what's wrong.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setValue((progressValue) =>
            progressValue < 61 ? progressValue + 1 : (progressValue = 0)
        );
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
if (progressValue === 60) {
    props.handleRefresh(); // calling the handleRefresh function passed from App.js
}
```

---

This one in particular smells like an overflow: a rerender-causing function called during the render phase (and we know `handleRefresh` to cause rerenders.

```
if (progressValue === 60) {
    props.handleRefresh(); // calling the handleRefresh function passed from App.js
}
```

---

Now, let's look for something that is supposed to stop the overflow (that is, it tries to set `progressValue` to something else than 60, once its 60).

Here it is:

```
progressValue < 61 ? progressValue + 1 : (progressValue = 0)
```

Except, this fires only every 1000ms. Which means for a whole second your component is stuck in a rerender-loop. Once it is set to `60`, React starts rendering like crazy and in a very short time gets past the render limit, while `progressValue` is still many, many milliseconds away from being set to 0.

---

An example solution would be to check for `progressValue === 60` in another effect.

```
export const CurrentWeatherForecast = (props) => {
    const { currentWeather } = props;
    const [progressValue, setValue] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setValue(prevProgressValue => prevProgressValue === 60 ? 0 : prevProgressValue + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => progressValue === 60 && props.handleRefresh(), [progressValue]);

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="file">Downloading progress:</label>
            <progress id="file" value={progressValue} max="60">
                {progressValue}%
        </progress>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: thanks for coming back to me. The above code definetely took me closer to the solution, the component doesn't re-render like crazy now. However I am getting another error "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state." I can see looking at the dev tools that step is getting updated to 0 in the handleRefresh, however the App.js component doesn't re-render which is exactly what the error says. Shouldn't setState cause an automatic re-render of the component ? @JohnSmith

Comment: @RobertoChirila Did you implement the second solution, the one that wraps handleRefresh in an effect?

Comment: @RobertoChirila I've updated the solution, give it a shot.

Comment: This gives me the same error above. The solution proposed below by @Pradip117 seems closer to what I need but still I can't get the component to re-render.

Comment: @RobertoChirila I missed two return statements, fixed now.  Not sure if that's it, but give it a try again.

Comment: Now the warning is still there but the state changes, however the component still doesn't re-render. Could this be because I am messing up state elsewhere and the shouldComponentUpdate doesn't fire properly ?

Comment: @RobertoChirila What do you mean by 'doesn't re-render'? Which component? Give us a screenshot of the error with the console open.

Comment: @RobertoChirila I've updated the solution, the warning should disappear.

Comment: Awesome. The warning was firing because we were using a `setState` inside a `setState`. (inside the hook's `setValue` we were calling parent's `this.handleRefresh`, which itself was calling `this.setState(data => ({...data, step:0})))`.

Comment: Right ! Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const CurrentWeatherForecast = ({ currentWeather }) => {

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
         props.handleRefresh();
    }, 60000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
   
return (
    <div>
        your codes goes here...
    </div>
);
};
```

Comment: This seems to update my state correctly in the parent component, I am looking in the dev tools and step changes from 0 to 1 and then from 1 to 0 accordingly but for some reason the component doesn't re-render. I have added a console.count("how many times") right after componentDidMount and the value is always 1. So the state changes but the component doesn't re-render.